# Inner join is very slow. How can I optimize?

Tags: mysql

I want to find the intersection of multiple queries on the time attribute.

I tried this inner joining of all of them, but it takes an extreme amount of time and never finishes.

```sql
    SELECT 
      pdx.time, 
      demand,
      pdx.temperature, 
      sea.temperature, 
      boi.temperature, 
      geg.temperature
    FROM capstone.aggregate_power_demands
    INNER JOIN  
      ( 
        SELECT time, temperature
        FROM capstone.weather
        WHERE location_name='PDX' AND time >= '1993' AND time <= '2018'
      ) as pdx
    ON aggregate_power_demands.time = pdx.time 
    INNER JOIN 
      ( 
        SELECT time, temperature 
        FROM capstone.weather
        WHERE location_name='SEA' AND time >= '1993' AND time <= '2018'
      ) as sea
    ON pdx.time = sea.time 
    INNER JOIN 
      ( 
        SELECT time, temperature 
        FROM capstone.weather
        WHERE location_name='BOI' AND time >= '1993' AND time <= '2018'
      ) as boi
    ON sea.time = boi.time
    INNER JOIN 
      ( 
        SELECT time, temperature
        FROM capstone.weather
        WHERE location_name='GEG' AND time >= '1993' AND time <= '2018'
      ) as geg
    ON boi.time = geg.time
```

[image]

Comment: What is type of a time column on which you are making join? Do you have indexes in all tables on this field?

Comment: it is a DATETIME, not sure what you mean by indexes

Comment: no I dont have indexes

Comment: which MySQL / MariaDB version you are using

Comment: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for macos10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Can you post a result sample or same sample data with table structure. I am nearly sure that you can arrive this with only one join.

Comment: @John Karasev - not interested ?

Comment: @John Karasev - which data type has **temperature**

Comment: @JohnKarasev you might want to try using `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: By the way, does `time` value in `aggregate_power_demands` table similar to `pdx.time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  aggregate_power_demands.time, 
  demand,
  pdx.temperature, 
  sea.temperature, 
  boi.temperature, 
  geg.temperature
FROM capstone.aggregate_power_demands
LEFT JOIN  
  (SELECT time, temperature
    FROM capstone.weather
    WHERE location_name='PDX' AND YEAR(time) BETWEEN '1993' AND '2018' 
GROUP BY location_name,time) as pdx
ON aggregate_power_demands.time = pdx.time 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT time, temperature 
    FROM capstone.weather
    WHERE location_name='SEA' AND YEAR(time) BETWEEN '1993' AND '2018' 
GROUP BY location_name,time) as sea
ON aggregate_power_demands.time = sea.time 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT time, temperature 
    FROM capstone.weather
    WHERE location_name='BOI' AND YEAR(time) BETWEEN '1993' AND '2018' 
GROUP BY location_name,time) as boi
ON aggregate_power_demands.time = boi.time
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT time, temperature
    FROM capstone.weather
    WHERE location_name='GEG' AND YEAR(time) BETWEEN '1993' AND '2018' 
GROUP BY location_name,time) as geg
ON aggregate_power_demands.time = geg.time;
```

Comment: I got some null values in the temperatures, is there a way to replace each null with the average in that location?

Comment: Also, what does the GROUP BY do?

Comment: which column you have null value @JohnKarasev ? `pdx.temperature` or
  `sea.temperature` or
  `boi.temperature` or
  `geg.temperature`?

Comment: @JohnKarasev , `GROUP BY` is to make sure that you only want one result per each `location_name` and `time`. You can remove it if you want but only if each `location_name` have different `time` and no values where one `location_name` have two `time` value that is similar.

Comment: boi.temperature has null,

Comment: Is there any data for `location_name="BOI"` in the table? If there is, was the year in `time` is between the condition `'1993' AND '2018'`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this. it has only one join:

```
SELECT 
      agd.time
    , agd.demand
    , MAX( IF( w.location_name = 'PDX', w.temperature, NULL)) as pdx_temperature
    , MAX( IF( w.location_name = 'SEA', w.temperature, NULL)) as sea_temperature
    , MAX( IF( w.location_name = 'BOI', w.temperature, NULL)) as boi_temperature
    , MAX( IF( w.location_name = 'GEG', w.temperature, NULL)) as geg_temperature
FROM capstone.aggregate_power_demands agd
LEFT JOIN capstone.weather w ON agd.time = w.time
WHERE w.location_name IN ( 'PDX' , 'SEA' , 'BOI' , 'GEG' )
AND agd.time BETWEEN '1993-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY w.location_name;
```

Comment: missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: and `MAX` must have `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have add change the answer to correct the errors. Thx  @John Karasev and @ tcadidot0